# x-api-key in request headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers

I am trying to retrieve fares between two different cities on a travel website. In the request headers, I see the following.

'x-api-idtoken':'null',
'x-api-key':'l7xx944d175ea25f4b9c903a583ea82a1c4c',

Do they change/expire with time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *could* change over time and in many cases do. Access keys/tokens can be given a limited life span, but it is up to the service in question to control refresh, expiration and/or revocation.

Given that the question does not contain an explicit reference to the web service involved, it is not possible to answer specifically for this case. Typically, the access management scheme is documented as part of the API.

Comment: they don't provide an API to retrieve the prices. I'm building a http request using python.But I understand that the api id token can change any time.